# Sencha Touch 2.2 is not working on Windows Phone 8

Tags: extjs, windows-phone-8, sencha-touch-2, internet-explorer-10

I have downloaded new ST 2.2 and new Cmd tools, generated app. I didn't do any changes to generated app. When I run the page in IE10 I see just blue screen with three white rects. I tried it in windows 8 browser and windows phone 8 emulator. Both failed

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Does your app work in other browser?

Take a look at the javascript console for errors...

Comment: Yes it does and on devices as well

Comment: Did you check the IE10 developer console? Maybe you're using the SQL proxy, IE does not support webDB..

Comment: Works for me with `sencha-touch-2.2.0-gpl` and `SenchaCmd-3.1.2.342`. White rects are there for me too, instead of the css3 dots animation, but after that application works fine.

Comment: Just to verify that your client is OK, I have a windows app written with the latest ST 2.2 and CMD. you can hit it at http://svcc.mobi  If that does not work, then it's your phone.  you will see the 3 dots first.

Comment: As said before, press F12 in IE10 to open the developer window and check the console tab for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in app.js

The path should be referring to your sencha touch js files folder

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    disableCaching: false,
    paths: {
        "Ext": 'lib/touch',// important to load sencha in windows phone
    }
});
```